# Nginx URL rewrite search?q=string (opencart)

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, nginx, opencart

I am trying to do

```
http://site.com/index.php?route=product/search&filter_name=QUERY
```

to

```
http://site.com/search?=QUERY
```

This is my rule; it does not work.

```
rewrite ^/search?q=(.*)?$ /index.php?route=product/search&filter_name=$1 last;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nginx doesn't allow you to match against the query string, instead it has an [$args](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables) variable and [if](http://nginx.org/r/if) -s. You can combine this to make the example work like this:

**(updated with an nginx if else statement)**

```
location /search {
    if ($args ~ "q=(?<q>.*)?") {
        rewrite ^ /index.php?route=product/search&filter_name=$q last;
    }
    # Else (if no search query entered from form)
    rewrite ^ /index.php?route=product/search last;
}
```

But since [if -s are considered evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) in nginx configs, you should use (in your case) the [try_files](http://nginx.org/r/try_files):

```
location /search
    try_files $uri /index.php?route=product/search&filter_name=$arg_q;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However I have updated my post. Can you please alter your answer

Comment: Updated, unfortunately the `try_files` had to be removed, but as long as you use rewrite ... last; it should be safe.

Comment: `try_files` was removed due it not supporting a more complex string? Thank you for the answer I really appreciate it.

Comment: Oh sorry, I've looked into the docs (again) and found it it can be done (-:

Comment: Can I do an else - basically I want /search on it's own to return a page and if it has parameters than run that command

Comment: Yes, by adding a `rewrite ^.*$  /index.php?route=whereever last;` under the `if` block.

Comment: Thanks, updated the post and repped your account with UP votes.

Comment: `^.*$` - is a CPU wasting. `^` - would be enough.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid it checks every symbol in the string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `$` sign. It needs to beforehand in this situation. Solution:

```
rewrite ^/search?q=$(.*)$ /search.php?q=$1? last;
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However I have updated my post. Can you please alter your answer